# Dispatcher doesn't throw an exception

Tags: java, exception, forward

I want to make the dispatcher throws an exception when I want to forward to non-existing resource, here's my code

```
 String page = (String) request.getAttribute("page");  //page to be forwarded form servlet to jsp
    if (page == null) {
        page = request.getParameter("page");//page to be forwarded form jsp to servlet
    }
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/InstitutionPages/" + page + ".jsp");
    try {
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        LogoutServlet.redirectToLoginPage(request, response);
    } catch (javax.servlet.ServletException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrarManagementServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        LogoutServlet.redirectToLoginPage(request, response);
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LogoutServlet.redirectToLoginPage(request, response);
    }
```

in page, I send invalid page name, but this error occurs on console

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "D:\versions\v30\OnlineQuerySystem_New\build\web\WEB-INF\InstitutionPages\Registerkk.jsp" not found
```

No one of Stack traces is printed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your servlet could look like:

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // do something at the servlet here

    String page = (String) req.getAttribute("page"); // page to be forwarded
                                                        // form servlet to
                                                        // jsp
    if (page == null) {
        page = req.getParameter("page");// page to be forwarded form jsp to
                                        // servlet
    }

    this.forwardIfExists(req, resp, page);

}

protected void forwardIfExists(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse resp, String page) throws ServletException, IOException {

    File pagePath = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath(page));

    if ( pagePath.exists() ) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher( page ).forward(req, resp);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format( "The page %s does not exist", page ));
    }

}

}
```

Also, do not catch the **ServletException** or **IOException** thrown by the servlet methods, if they happened something really bad is happening in your application and you should not swallow these exceptions as you are in your code. These exceptions should be be left as they are and the container should catch them. You should **log** them and not try to print the stack traces, as this is going to print at the err stream and will not be visible at a production server.

Comment: The same, the exception should occur when making forward

Comment: 1- getRealPath does't reach the files inside web-inf.
2- when throwing exceptions in doGet() makes all exceptions appear in the jsp pages, and that is not recommended.

Comment: Yes it does, that's exactly what getRealPath is supposed to do, reach a file anywhere inside your web application. And while showing exceptions in JSP pages is not recommended, swallowing exceptions is even worse. When something wrong happens you should just send the user to a common error page instead of sending him to the login.