# why does no 404 error occur if forwarding to a jsp that does not exist?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'd like to redirect to a 404 page, if a request dispatcher points to a jsp that does not exist. However I don't know how, because I don't get any exceptions or null value.

example: there is no blablabla.jsp

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("blablabla.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

web.xml:

```
   <servlet>
            <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>creator.controllers.MainController</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jspx</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're forwarding: the endpoint of the request *does* exist; it's the content you're attempting to put into the response that doesn't, which is something different.

What would be the purpose of a user-level error for a development-level bug?

You could do something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886441/dispatcher-doesnt-throw-an-exception) and return a 404 instead, but IMO this is working around a development-level issue that should be handled by integration (or functional) testing.